# reach variable outside of foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm using linq for search function. I have to search by a list of locations(display students from Tokio,Berlin, New York). I have a foreach statement, which is going throu all the locations and adds them to a list. My problem is that I can't dispaey them all outside of foreach. How can I declare var newstudents before foreach?

Bellow is my code

```
public void search(IEnumerable<string> Location)
{
    foreach (var l in Location)
    {
        var students = from s in db.Students select s;
        students = students.Where(s => s.City.Contains(l));
        var customers = students.ToList();                  
     }
     int custIndex = 1;
     Session["TopEventi"] = customers.ToDictionary(x => custIndex++, x => x);
     ViewBag.TotalNumberCustomers = customers.Count();
```

Comment: Declare `var customers = students.ToList();` before the `foreach`

Comment: sorry, but students are declaired inside of forecah

Comment: Then dont! And all this can be done in one line of code anyway. `var students  = db.Students.Where(x => x.City.Any(x => Location.Contains(x));`

Comment: So are you trying to create a dictionary of `customers` per `location`? Or are you trying to create a global dictionary and put that into your session? The code intent is unclear.

Comment: I just wan't to display customers from locations(Tokio,Berlin,New York)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the loop entirely.

```
public void search(IEnumerable<string> Location)
{
       string[] locations = Location.Cast<string>().ToArray();
       var customers = db.Students.Where(s => locations.Contains(s.City)).ToList();
```

Comment: OP is using a substring search whereas you are looking for the complete location.

Comment: @TimSchmelter From the question the OP is passing in the full city name, so I based my answer on that. Perhaps this is what they're actually looking for?

Comment: Not really, OP is using `s.City.Contains(l)` where `l` is the location-string, and `Student.City` is also a `string`. Then it's [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a substring search whereas your `locations.Contains(s.City)` is using [`List.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) which compares the complete string.

Comment: Yeah I see what the OP is doing ok, but in the question itself they said `I have to search by a list of locations(display students from Tokio,Berlin, New York).` which are the complete names of the locations.

Comment: Sure, the locations are complete city-names. But `Student.City` could contain other informations like the zipcode. However, he has a solution for both now ;)

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is that I can't display them all outside of `foreach`. How
>   can I declare `var newstudents` before `foreach`?

Why can't you do that? You just need to declare the variable as `IEnumerable<ClassName>`:

```
IEnumerable<Student> customers = null;
foreach (var l in Location)
{
    var students = from s in db.Students
                   where s.City.Contains(l)
                   select s;

    customers = customers.Concat(students);                  
}
customers = customers.ToList()
```

But you don't need the `foreach` at all, you can do it with one LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<Student> customers = db.Students
    .Where(s => Location.Any(l => s.City.Contains(l)));
```

This approach is searching for a substring in `Student.City` which is the location.

Comment: This would overwrite the values of the List in each loop or ?

Comment: @ConstantinTreiber: true, so i've now modified the example to use `Concat`. But the second approach seems much better.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the List outside the foreach and in side you only do something like

```
yourList.AddRange(students.ToList());
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but as it seems OP doesn't have the understanding of programming for this to be enough to solve his problem, maybe you should expand upon your answer with explanation

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a dictionary for mapping your new student to specific location, and add new lists to it in the loop.

also your use of the word newstudents is a bit confusing - you're nor lookning here new students in your code only map their location. Anyways: considerung new students from outside the loop:

```
public void search(IEnumerable<string> Location)
{
    Dictionary<Location, List<Students>> newStudents = new  Dictionary<Location, List<Students>>();
    foreach (var l in Location)
    {
        var students = from s in db.Students select s;
        students = students.Where(s => s.City.Contains(l));
        newStudents[l]= students.ToList();                  
     }
     int custIndex = 1;
    //what is this for?  seeing lastly added 
     Session["TopEventi"] = customers.ToDictionary(x => custIndex++, x => x);
     ViewBag.TotalNumberCustomers = (from  lists in newStudents select  lists.Count).Sum();
```

Comment: if you wan to simply map the students to the cities they come from (that is what your code actually does) the best answer is @BarryO'Kane